# Unity - How can I add or subtract a chosen number of degrees from an angle?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, angle, quaternions, degrees

I was wondering if there's a way to add (in my case) 120 degrees **everytime** I push 'ButtonA', and subtract 120 degrees **everytime** I push 'ButtonB', from the **Z-axis rotation** of a 2d sprite (prefab).

This is the code I'm using at the moment, but it only rotates once left, and once right:

```
function TouchOnScreen ()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.touches[0];
        if (touch.position.x < Screen.width/2)
        {
            var RSpeed = 10.0f
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp ( transform.rotation,Quaternion.Euler(0,0,120), Time.deltaTime*RSpeed);
            Debug.Log("RotateRight");
        }
        else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width/2)
        {
            var LSpeed = 10.0f
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp ( transform.rotation,Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-120), Time.deltaTime*LSpeed);
            Debug.Log("RotateLeft");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Note: Please use unityscript if you can, I'm pretty new to coding and unityscript is all I know so far.

Answer (score 0):

From the [online documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) it is shown that the signature of the function is

```
static function Lerp(from: Quaternion, to: Quaternion, t: float): Quaternion;
```

that means the second parameter is the new rotation of the object not the rotation offset

you should use something of the sort

```
function TouchOnScreen ()
{
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    var touch = Input.touches[0];
    if (touch.position.x < Screen.width/2)
    {
        var RSpeed = 10.0f
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp ( transform.rotation,transform.rotation + Quaternion.Euler(0,0,120), Time.deltaTime*RSpeed);
        Debug.Log("RotateRight");
    }
    else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width/2)
    {
        var LSpeed = 10.0f
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp ( transform.rotation,transform.rotation + Quaternion.Euler(0,0,-120), Time.deltaTime*LSpeed);
        Debug.Log("RotateLeft");
    }
}
}
```

note the second parameter is `transform.rotation + Quaternion.Euler(0,0,120)` (current rotation + offset to the right)

I'm not an expert on unity engine (I only started toying with the free version yesterday, literally)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @workoverflow, but I'm getting this error: BCE0051: Operator '+' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' and a right hand side of type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function TouchOnScreen ()
{
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    var touch = Input.touches[0];
    if (touch.position.x < Screen.width/2)
    {
        var RSpeed = 10.0f
        transform.Rotate(0,0,120);
        Debug.Log("RotateRight");
    }
    else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width/2)
    {
        var LSpeed = 10.0f
        transform.Rotate(0,0,-120);
        Debug.Log("RotateLeft");
    }
}
}
```

If this not works try with Gameobject. I didn't check this

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rasa Mohamed , but the problem with this script is, is that the rotation isn't smoothly. It snaps from point A to point B in one frame. I want it so that the rotation is visible.